# Консоль и Sublime Text 3

Tags: bash, sublime-text

https://youtu.be/5JEkiHHUOFs?list=PL363QX7S8MfSxcHzvkNEqMYbOyhLeWwem&t=33
Sorax создал через консоль папку и два файла. Это я смог сделать. Дальше он ввел в консоль английскую "**o**" и открылась созданная папка с файлами. У меня это не сработало. [image: Изображение 1]

После он ввел "**sublime .**" и открылся Sublime с этой папкой. Это у меня тоже не сработало.

Вопрос: как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Полагаю, что нужно настроить bash или что там используется. Добавить путь к sublime в PATH (лучше, пожалуй, в PATH одного лишь bash) или указать некий alias, например (что-то вроде `alias sublime='<путь к папке Sublime Text>/subl.exe'`), или добавить функцию в инициализирующий скрипт (чтобы, например, сразу и пути конвертировать). С `o`, опять же, какой-нибудь alias. Например,

```
alias o='$WINDIR/explorer .'
```